# Iptables - Why spammers still able to access even the IP ranges were blocked?

Tags: centos, iptables, apache-httpd, firewall

I have some spammer from russian, i put the following range of IP in my IPtables, but still they are able to access port 80, 443 of my web-server.

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -s 4.53.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 173.205.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 37.9.0.0/16 -j DROP

-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

What am i missing? I wanted to block those ranges 37.9.*, 173.205.*, 4.53.*

Answer (score 1):

`-I` inserts a rule at the beginning, `-A` at the end. Because you are appending all the rules, the accept port `443` will be higher in the list than the range drops.

When a packet is received only the first matching rule is applied.

Comment: How would be my script? from line 5 put those lines? (-A INPUT -s 4.53.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 173.205.0.0/16 -j DROP
-A INPUT -s 37.9.0.0/16 -j DROP) ? and all the rest after those DROP lines you mean?

Comment: Yes, and remember to allow the ssh port if you are connecting through ssh or you will be locked out of the server!

Comment: Can you re-test and re-update the final version. Cause there are tons of new visitor readers read answers and if they put wrong line in wrong order they will be locked forever. Please EDIT your answer